# Oracle query, get highest version and status of highest version

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table that for simplicity has three columns:

```
process_name
version
status
```

there will be many rows where `process_name` is the same string value, say "apple", but for n "apple" rows, `version` is going to be from 1-n where `n` is the highest version.

Status for simplicity will be `0` or `1`.

In a nutshell, I want to get a list of processes, the highest version, AND the part I'm not getting, the status /of the highest version/.  Here's my query which fails:

```
select p.process_name, max(p.version), p2.status from process_definition p 
LEFT JOIN process_definition p2 ON p.process_name = p2.process_name AND p2.version = max(p.version) 
group by p.name order by p.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aggregation:

```
select process_name, max(version) as version,
       max(status) keep (dense_rank first order by version desc) as status
from process_definition pd
group by process_name;
```

This [`keep`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) syntax is Oracle's rather verbose way of implementing a "first" aggregation function.